# Handling the nitty-gritty with fate

Tags: fate, fate-core, hexcrawl

I am working on a campaign in a medieval fantasy setting using fate. I have decided to use a hexcrawl as a convenient way to give interesting choices to my players letting them lead the story and more easily geologically locate different elements in the game universe.

I have seen a lot of people suggest using some form of supplies system with hexcrawl as it allows for interesting decisions during the game (should we go farther and risk running out or take this other path that is closer to civilization) however I wonder how to handle this in the context of fate.

Should I just fix a number of days of supplies they can carry and handle things like resupplying in a forest individually? Would using the bronze rule to model their supplies as a character with a stress track be appropriate?

I have a feeling the rules of fate core are made to discourage me from adding mechanics that involve such details especially since wealth isn't numerical by default. Is that an exaggeration or should I be very careful introducing that kind of details in fate?

Comment: Gritty detail is exactly what Fate doesn't do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The bronze rule is quite modular. You do not need to flesh out a whole character. You may just do fine with a bare "Supplies" stress track, which gets attacked by circumstances, events and some sorts of player actions, and is defended by player skills. It probably gets cleared when the team has a chance to resupply.

If the supply challenges are important to your story, you may add a couple of consequence slots that get filled with aspects like "Low on water" or "The taste of fungus isn't so bad"

If you want the supplies to help with advancing the story, you may add some aspect slots to be filled by the players, like "Mountain dwarf ale", or "Lots of arrows". But these can also be done by creating advantages while resupplying.

If the supplies are big enough to dig up almost anything when needed, you may give it some skills to represent how probable it is to find a specific kind of thing when needed. Like Great(+4) Weapons, and Fair(+2) Food&Drink